# R getReturns > cannot open HTTP status was '404 not found'

Tags: r

Using R (I'm a R newbie). I installed stockPortfolio and quadProg packages.

I'm trying to run `returns <- getReturns(names(stocks), freq="week")`
but I'm getting the error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

How do I troubleshoot and fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following command:

```
returns <- getReturns(stocks, freq="week")
```

It shouldn't give error now.

Comment: 404 would seem to indicate that a web service cannot be reacbed.